# Overlapping text when resizing the browser horizontally in Clarity 0.9.14

Tags: vmware-clarity

Form fields overlap when the Viewport size is smaller. Is there a way that the form fields snap on the next line when the space is not enough?

Code Snippet:

```
<form class="compact">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <section class="form-block">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="aForm_1">This is a form field</label>
                  <input type="text" id="aForm_1" placeholder="Enter value here" size="45">
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <section class="form-block">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="aForm_2">Overlapping Text</label>
                  <input type="text" id="aForm_2" placeholder="Enter value here" size="45">
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Here is the plunker:
https://embed.plnkr.co/ynfi39fIMk1bc8bSBHAp/

[overlapping text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YVES.gif)

Answer (score 5):

@X.Vu: Please take a look at this Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/6YhGmFusvo5EdySzxNpn?p=preview

and also the Clarity Forms in Grid documentation here:
https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/forms

You need to add the `.row` class with `.form-group` as mentioned in the documentation and then use the `.col-*` classes on the form fields.

```
<form class="compact">
        <section class="form-block">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <label for="aForm_1">This is a form field</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <input type="text" id="aForm_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter value here" size="45">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <label for="aForm_2">Overlapping Text</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <input type="text" id="aForm_2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter value here" size="45">
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </form>
```

Also notice that I have added the `.form-control` class on `input` as that makes the `input` occupy the entire `.col-*` space assigned to it.